# How to set ProgressBarForeground in MahApps.Metro ProgressDialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I want to change the color of the progressbar inside of an ProgressDialog to HighlightColor.

With a CustomResourceDictionary i managed to change the button-style but not the color of the Progressbar

```
    MetroDialogOptions.CustomResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary
    {
        Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/GUI;component/Styles/DialogDictionary.xaml")
    };
```

DialogDictionary.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="AccentedDialogSquareButton" 
        BasedOn="{StaticResource HighlightedSquareButtonStyle}" 
        TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
    <Setter Property="Controls:ControlsHelper.ContentCharacterCasing" Value="Normal" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Dialog:ProgressDialog}" 
                   x:Key="NewProgressDialogStyle" 
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Dialog:ProgressDialog}}">
    <Setter Property="ProgressBarForeground" Value="Red" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Dialog:ProgressDialog}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource NewProgressDialogStyle}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible.

The `ProgressBarForeground` property is set to a local value using the [`SetResourceReference`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.setresourcereference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, so using a `Setter` in a `Style` has no effect - the local value always has a higher priority than the one coming from a `Style`.

You could try overriding the `AccentColorBrush` resource in your custom dictionary, but that won't work because the current theme code in Mahapps will scan all the merged resource dictionaries of the dialog and replace this resource with a special one that is defined as the "theme accent color".

See [`ThemeManager`](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro.Shared/ThemeManager/ThemeManager.cs) source code for details.

You have only two options:

- change the accent color of your theme to the desired progress bar color (but then many controls will use this color for their appearance)
- post a change request to the Mahapps team so that they provide a possibility to override the progress bar color in the `ProgressDialog`